# Azure Active Directory Allowing access from another tenant

Tags: azure-active-directory

My organization is currently using Azure AD for all our employees and internal applications. I am building a web service which needs to use Azure AD for authentication but they want me to use a separate tenant so that customer users aren't all mixed in with all of our employees. They want me to make it so a few handpicked employee users can sign into the web app, but using their account from our main tenant. The customer users should be able to use their emails as their usernames, regardless of which email system they use. The customer users should also be able to reset their own passwords.

I thought that Azure B2C was the answer because when I created a B2C tenant, I was able to login using my user from the employee tenant as well as send email invites to external users at any email address. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to add another user from an `External Azure Active Directory`.

It would also be nice if I could setup some external providers, such as google, facebook, etc, which seems to be right up B2C's alley, but I can't seem to add users from another Azure AD

Is there a better solution to what I am doing here that meets my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It would also be nice if I could setup some external providers, such as google, facebook, etc, which seems to be right up B2C's alley, but I can't seem to add users from another Azure AD

To allow sign-in for the **specific Azure AD organization**, check the below:

Create an **Azure AD Application in the AAD Tenant** and add the redirect URI as `https://your-B2C-tenant-name.b2clogin.com/your-B2C-tenant-name.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp`

[image]

Now, Go to Azure AD B2C Tenant to add **Azure AD as the Identity Provider**:

*Select Azure AD B2C -> Identity Providers -> New OpenID Connect provider*

In the Metadata URL, add `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`

Enter the ClientID, Client Secret of the Azure AD Application. And for Identity provider claims mapping, check the below and Save:

- **User ID**:  oid
- **Display name**:  name
- **Given name**:  given_name
- **Surname**:  family_name
- **Email**:  email

[image]

Created an **Azure AD B2C user flow, and select the Identity Provider** and save like below:

[image]

I created an **Azure AD User in AAD Tenant** like below:

[image]

Run the user flow:

[image]

Select **Azure AD to sign in with AAD user account**:

[image]

Sign-in with the Azure AD User:

[image]

**The user gets signed in successfully like below:**

[image]

When I go to ***Azure AD B2C -> Users -> The above user is added as the Member*** like below:

[image]

***Otherwise***, you can make use of **Azure AD B2B collaboration** which allows external identity providers such as Facebook, Google and will allow users to sign-in with their existing accounts. And you can also invite users (from other organization) to access the applications.

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure AD B2B collaboration overview - Microsoft Entra](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/what-is-b2b)

Comment: Well, got it working. Thank you. The only piece that was missing is that 'profile' needs to be added to the scopes when you setting up Azure AD as an identity provider