# Azure B2C not calling logout endpoint of openid identity provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, msal-angular

I have two Azure AD tenants, a primary one and a B2C one. The B2C tenant is setup to use the primary Azure AD as an openid connect IDP for reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76485935/azure-active-directory-allowing-access-from-another-tenant/76489635#76489635).

I am using the `msal-angular` library on the client app. And I can successfully login using the primary AD account. However, when I logout and then sign in again, I can choose my IDP again, but it just silently signs in the last user that was authenticated, even though I specify `loginRedirect({prompt:'login'})`.

I that B2C doesn't call the logout endpoint for any of it's IDP's and I think its because the user may not want to logout from other sites as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-user-flow#sign-out). The other reason could be that different IDPs could implement logouts differently and so B2C just opts not to call them directly.

Preferably, I would want to setup the IDP so that it will allow me to select from all signed in accounts or even select a new account instead of just silently signing on whichever account was logged in last. Is there any way to do that?

If not, I have a bit of code which checks for the AzureAD identity provider in the claims and redirects to the Azure AD logout page after B2C logs out:

```
public logoutRedirect() {
  if(this.currentUser?.idTokenClaims?.idp == "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mainTenantId}/v2.0"){
    let clientId = environment.azureClientId;
    let postPostLogoutRedirectUri = encodeURI(window.location.origin)
    this.msalService.logoutRedirect({postLogoutRedirectUri: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{mainTenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?client_id=${clientId}&post_logout_redirect_url=${postPostLogoutRedirectUri}`});
  }
  else{
    this.msalService.logoutRedirect();
  }
}
```

This works, and allows me to sign out of my account, but the problem is that the post_redirect_url parameter doesn't seem to work and I think the reason is that the session has already been cleared by the B2C logout so it doesn't view the redirect url as safe to navigate to. Perhaps there's a better way to do this?